# Create a function that deletes downloaded files

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using this sample code:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py

I use the !yt command because the !play command has stability issues.
I need to create a function that eliminates downloaded music files. I had thought of deleting the entire folder every time a song was played but the idea does not seem so brilliant to me. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: You could delete the message that contains the file if it has a specific extension if that's what you mean.

Comment: When I run a song, a file is downloaded to the bot folder, my goal is to delete those files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to put this in a command,

```
@bot.command(name='del')
@commands.is_owner #only bot owner can use this
for folder in os.listdir('./foldermp3filesarestored'):
    if folder.endswith('.mp3'):
        os.remove(folder) 
    else:
        print("found file not ending in .mp3")
```

You could put this in a for loop in on_ready too.